# Body parameters in POST request with capitals

Tags: ruby, httparty

I need to send a POST request with HTTParty, in which the body parameter must be `shortDescription`. Should I use:

```
payload = { :short_description => "Bla" }
```

or:

```
payload = { :shortDescription => "Bla" }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Pass payload like this:

```
payload = { :shortDescription => "Bla" }
```

or:

```
payload = { "shortDescription" => "Bla" }
```

Comment: Do you have explanation for this ? Why did you choose this one !